# Error: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: c#, xml, linq, compiler-errors, linq-to-xml

I have a xml like this:

```
<countries>
    <country ID="MX">
        <idea ID="Valor1">nota1</idea>
        <idea ID="Valor2">nota2</idea>
        <idea ID="Valor3">nota3</idea>
        <idea ID="Valor4">nota4</idea>
    </country>
    <country ID="US">
        <idea ID="Valor1">nota1</idea>
        <idea ID="Valor2">nota2</idea>
        <idea ID="Valor3">nota3</idea>
        <idea ID="Valor4">nota4</idea>
    </country>
</countries>
```

With LINQ to XML how can i get a list of specific type? I tried something like this:

I created a class:

```
public class Ideas
{
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public List<ListItem> ListIdeas { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use this class to make a list:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(this.Server.MapPath("~/config/ideas.xml"));

var cat = from p in xdoc.Descendants("countries")
                        .Elements("country")
                        .Select(m => new Ideas 
                            {
                                Country = m.Attribute("ID").Value, 
                                ListIdeas = m.Elements("idea")
                                             .Select(c => 
                                                 new ListItem 
                                                 {
                                                     Text = c.Attribute("ID").Value , 
                                                     Value = c.Value
                                                 }).ToList()
                            });
```

But I get the next error:

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause
>
> The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.

Answer (score 4):

You mix Query syntax and Extension Methods syntax. Choose **one**.

```
var r = (from c in xdoc.Element("countries")
                       .Elements("country")
         select new Country
         {
             ID = c.Attribute("ID").Value,
             Ideas = (from i in c.Elements("idea")
                      select new Idea
                      {
                          Text = i.Attribute("ID").Value, 
                          Value = i.Value
                      }).ToList()
         }).ToList();
```

Notice I renamed your classes and properties for better readability.

---

The same by in another syntax:

```
var q = xdoc.Element("countries")
            .Elements("country")
            .Select(c => new Country
                 {
                      ID = c.Attribute("ID").Value,
                      Ideas = c.Elements("idea")
                               .Select(i => new Idea
                                   {
                                       Text = i.Attribute("ID").Value, 
                                       Value = i.Value
                                   })
                               .ToList()
                 })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing select at the end. Try:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(this.Server.MapPath("~/config/ideas.xml"));

List<Ideas> cat = from p in xdoc.Descendants("countries").Elements("country")
                         .Select(m => new Ideas 
                             {
                                 Country = m.Attribute("ID").Value, 
                                 ListIdeas = m.Elements("idea")
                                 .Select(c => 
                                     new ListItem 
                                     {
                                         Text = c.Attribute("ID").Value , 
                                         Value = c.Value
                                     }).ToList()
                             }) select p;
```

Comment: imo, a good answer should use Query syntax or Extension Methods syntax, one of them, not a mix.