# Creating an observable collection using linq to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

When creating a an observable collection of objects from an xml document using linq are there any pitfalls one needs to worry about?  I seem to be running into trouble doing this and I am not certain why that is the case. The following code is telling me that I mismatching a PatientModel and an Observable collection of Patient models.  But I don't know that to necessarily be the case.  Am I missing something here?  I thought I drilled down to the right layer.  Admittedly, my linq skills leave muc.h to be desired.  I am confident with your help I can take this over the goal line so to speak

```
        patsModel = (ObservableCollection<PatientModel>)
            from templatesList in xDocument.Descendants("TemplateData")
                select new ObservableCollection<PatientModel> {(
                    from template in templatesList.Elements("ACOData")                        
                    select new PatientModel {
                        EncounterId = ValueOrMin(Convert.ToInt32(template.Element("FOCUSED_READMISSIONS_ID").Value)),
                        PatientId = ValueOrMin(Convert.ToInt32(template.Element("PATIENT_ID").Value)), 
                        EMPIID = template.Element("EMPI").Value, 
                        PopulationPatientID = ValueOrMin(Convert.ToInt32(template.Element("POPULATION_PATIENT_ID").Value)), 
                        FirstName = template.Element("FIRST_NAME").Value, 
                        LastName = template.Element("LAST_NAME").Value,                            
                        Active = template.Element("ACTIVE").Value, 
                    })
                };
```

When I add .ToList()

to the second to last line... 
I get the following exception...

```
Error   19  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FRACOApplication.Models.PatientModel>' to 'FRACOApplication.Models.PatientModel'
```

which tells me I am mismatching something somewhere.  It is expecting a List of PatientModels and it is only getting a PatientModel.  Not sure what I am doing wrong there.  How does one select a list of something from xml?

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of problems here.
First thing first I needed to make sure I wasn't mixing up  Query syntax and Extension Methods syntax
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487508/729820)

Although in the above example I wasn't doing that, in my zeal to fix my problem I ended up doing that.  Also, I had a comma at the end of my select statements.
Anyway, in the end, I did this...

```
        patsModel = (ObservableCollection<PatientModel>)
            //from templateData in 
              xDocument.Element("TemplateData").Elements("ACOData")
             .Select( template => new PatientModel {
                        EncounterId = ValueOrMin(Convert.ToInt32(template.Element("FOCUSED_READMISSIONS_ID").Value)),
                        PatientId = ValueOrMin(Convert.ToInt32(template.Element("PATIENT_ID").Value)), 
                        EMPIID = template.Element("EMPI").Value, 
                        PopulationPatientID = ValueOrMin(Convert.ToInt32(template.Element("POPULATION_PATIENT_ID").Value)), 
                        FirstName = template.Element("FIRST_NAME").Value, 
                        LastName = template.Element("LAST_NAME").Value,                             
                        Active = template.Element("ACTIVE").Value
             });
```